# AJAX not receiving PHP response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My ajax request puts files into the directory.
However I receive no response from the PHP file.

I'm using alerts to determine if a response has been received.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function doodleSave() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("doodle-canvas");
  var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  $.ajax({
    url:'test.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{ data:canvasData },
    success: function(response){
      alert(response);
      //echo what the server sent back...
    }
  });
}
```

```
<?php

/* AUTOMATED VARIABLES */
$upload_dir = "images/external/doodles/";
$url            = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$unique_post_id = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$timestamp      = time();
$nature         = "doodle";
$imageUrl       = $upload_dir.$url.'.png';

$img = $_POST['data'];
$img = substr($img,strpos($img,",")+1);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir . $url . ".png";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);


if(!$success) {

  exit('unable to upload'); // Prints success and exit the script

} else {

  exit($file); // Prints success and exit the script

}

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

I success and error to ajax and it comes up as an error.:

```
function doodleSave() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("doodle-canvas");
  var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  $.ajax({
    url:'test.php',
    type:'POST',
    data:{ data:canvasData },
      success: function(){
        alert('success');
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('failure');
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: If you look at the request in your network console, what http response code is the XHR request getting?  I'm unaware of how exit() will affect the response code of the request, so it's possible that it is returning an error response code.  In which case you may want to use `header()` to specify the request response code rather than using exit().  such as `header("HTTP/1.0 200 Ok")` or `header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request")`

Comment: I looked at the XHR responses and they're all for my notification checker which runs every 10 seconds. Nothing on this upload script

Comment: But things are still saving to the directory when I press the doodleSave button

Comment: Sorry, I must have not seen it:
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Alright in that case that is why you are not seeing your success.  I suspect the exit() may be the culprit.  To test this you can try to comment out the exits and just let the script end normally.  If this results in a 200 then you know that is the issue.  And if it is, I refer you to my first comment about using header() instead to denote the success of the request to the client

Comment: Try with `echo` instead of `exit`.

Comment: @Taplar `exit()` is the normal way to end a PHP script, it shouldn't cause an error. Giving it a string argument is just short for echoing the string before exiting.

Comment: That's working great @taplar, I'm getting 200. Can I retrieve the $imageUrl variable back into ajax?

Comment: @Sam Sure you could put it in an associative array and then do `echo json_encode($theArray)` to return it to the client.

Comment: @Sam Read it more carefully. If the argument is an integer, it's treated as a status code. If it's a string, it's just a message to print before exiting.

Comment: It is not returning it. I am having no alert.

Comment: @Sam you want to get the file anme from AJAX?

Comment: Yes please. The ajax is returning as error however the files are uploading..

Comment: Replace `error: function(){ alert('failure'); }` **by** `error: function( request, status, error ){ alert(error); }` to see what really is that Ajax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode` to send data back with AJAX.

```
<?php

/* AUTOMATED VARIABLES */
$upload_dir = "images/external/doodles/";
$url            = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$unique_post_id = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$timestamp      = time();
$nature         = "doodle";
$imageUrl       = $upload_dir.$url.'.png';

$img = $_POST['data'];
$img = substr($img,strpos($img,",")+1);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir . $url . ".png";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
if(!$success) {

    echo json_encode(['filename' => false]);
    exit(); // Prints success and exit the script

} else {

   echo json_encode(['filename' => $file]);
   exit();
}

?>
```

In your AJAX do this

```
function doodleSave() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("doodle-canvas");
    var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    $.ajax({
        url:'test.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:{ data:canvasData },
        success: function(response){
            var data = JSON.parse(response);
            if (data.filename != false) {
                alert(data.filename);
            }else {
                alert('unable to upload');
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('failure');
        }
    });
}
```

You can also use `$.post()` which is a shorthand for `$.ajax()` for `POST` request.

```
function doodleSave() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("doodle-canvas");
    var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    $.post('test.php', {data: canvasData}, function (response) {
        var data = JSON.parse(response);
        if (data.filename != false) {
            alert(data.filename);
        } else {
            alert('unable to upload');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I've done this word for word and I don't get any alert. I've checked the console and it responds with 200

Comment: is your PHP file `test.php`?

Comment: I was using the entire http://www.website....etc. Just changed it to just the name and extension and it works fine! Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace all spaces with plus sign (+).

Your code with a fix:

```
<?php

/* AUTOMATED VARIABLES */
$upload_dir = "images/external/doodles/";
$url            = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$unique_post_id = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$timestamp      = time();
$nature         = "doodle";
$imageUrl       = $upload_dir.$url.'.png';

$img = $_POST['data'];
$img = substr($img,strpos($img,",")+1);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img); // Here is a fix
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir . $url . ".png";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);


if(!$success) {

  exit('unable to upload'); // Prints success and exit the script

} else {

  exit($file); // Prints success and exit the script

}

?>
```

Comment: Still not receiving a response for the $file variable

Comment: @Sam the image will be uploaded and save successfully?

Comment: It uploads successfully but I need to return the location back to AJAX

Comment: @Sam Try to replace the condition of if to `if( $success === false )`